# Ubuntu already installed on HDD. Error while trying to boot from it when plugged in externally

Tags: boot, grub2, hard-drive

I suspect connectivity issues between an internal HDD and the motherboard that I can't easily fix, and that make the system unusable. Ubuntu is already installed on the drive.

As a workaround, I thought of connecting the drive externally through a hard drive enclosure, but as I try to boot from it, I run into the following Grub error:

```
error: file `/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod´ not found.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>
```

I tried to use boot repair with no success, and thought of a conflict between legacy/UEFI install and boot methods, but I'm not knowledgable enough to work that out. Any idea what's going on?

**EDIT 22 June 18:** I could solve my root problem thanks to jon athan, but my question remains open. My guess is that the drive uses a GPT partition scheme and Ubuntu was installed in UEFI mode, and that, for some reason, I'm forced to boot in legacy mode when plugged in through the docking station. So it expects to see a legacy Grub and looks for `/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod` which doesn't exist.

Comment: Which hardware do you use?

Comment: The drive is a Toshiba MQ01ABD075 on an Asus F552C. I use an Advance BX-3003U31 docking station to connect it externally.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 free toolkits that will help you investigate your problem: 
A- Hiren's boot CD, http://www.hirensbootcd.org/download/ 
B- Ultimate boot CD, http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/ultimate_boot_cd_(ubcd).html) 
In order to use them you may have to switch your BIOS mode from UEFI to Legacy. Legacy mode is less secured & thus less restrictive than UEFI.
You'll be able to run all sorts of tests on your hardware.
Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I could remap all bad sectors on the disk thanks to Vivard included in the Ultimate Boot CD. There were errors on the EFI partition, which explains why I couldn't boot. Then I erased the disk and made a fresh install. It looks good up to now!